# Does the inequality $c_a \le xy^{y^a/x^a} + yx^{x^a/y^a} - x^a - y^a \le C_a$ hold?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality

**Update**: [Posted in MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/446436/what-are-the-bounds-of-xyya-xa-yxxa-ya-xa-ya-for-0-le-x-le) since it is unanswered in MSE

Let $0 \le x,y \le 1$ and $a$ be a real. Consider the function

$$
f(x,y,a) = xy^{y^a/x^a} + yx^{x^a/y^a} -  x^a - y^a \tag 1
$$

For a fixed $a$, the graph of the maximum and the minimum value of $f(x,y,a)$ shown below.

[image]

The graph shows that for $a \ge 1$, there is a constant $C_a$ depending only in $a$ such that $xy^{y^a/x^a} + yx^{x^a/y^a} -  y^a - x^a \le C_a$ and similarly for $a \le 2$, there is a constant $c_a$ such that $c_a \le xy^{y^a/x^a} + yx^{x^a/y^a} -  y^a - x^a$. Also, $0\ <a < 2$ is the only interval in which $f(x,y,a)$ has non-zero maxima and minima for every $a$.

Some experimentally observed examples of inequalities belonging to this family are

$$
-\frac{1}{2} \le xy^{y/x} + yx^{x/y} - x - y < 0 \tag 2
$$

$$
0 \le xy^{y^2/x^2} + yx^{x^2/y^2} -  x^2 - y^2 \le \frac{1}{4} \tag 3
$$

$$
0 \le xy^{y^4/x^4} + yx^{x^4/y^4} -  x^4 - y^4 \le \frac{1}{2} \tag 4
$$

**Question 1**: Can we prove that for every real $a$, there exists $c_a$ and $C_a$ such that

$$
c_a \le xy^{y^a/x^a} + yx^{x^a/y^a} -  x^a - y^a \le C_a
$$

**Question 2**: Can we express $c_a$ and $C_a$ in terms of $a$?

Comment: Do you want to prove the inequality in the title i.e. $a = 2$, or answer your Question 1, 2?

Comment: @RiverLi I have updated the title to make it consistent

Comment: I think the more fitting title would be like "for some constants $c_a,C_a$" instead of "for all $a$", because the latter is implicitly implied by the former.

Comment: Is $a$ positive or any sign?

Comment: note that since $y^a/x^a \ge 0$ we have $0 \le y^{y^a/x^a} \le 1$ for $0 \le y \le 1$ so the expression is at most $x+y-x^a-y^a \le 2$ for example and at least $-x^a-y^a$ which is bounded inferior for $a \ge 0$ by $-2$; of course if $a<0$ the expression is inferior unbounded as fixing $y$ and letting $x \to 0$ say makes it go to minus infinity; the better question is of tighter bounds eg for which $a$ the expression is non negative etc

Comment: @Conrad If $a$ can be negative it does not work, that is why I asked.

Comment: @Aleksandr yes if $a<0$ the expression is unbounded inferior as noted